# Scraping the data of the advent of code in js

Tags: javascript

i m trying to scrap the input of the advent of code. For that i use this code:

```js
import got from 'got';


(async () =>{
    const url = 'https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1/input'
    try {
        const response = await got.get(url);
        console.log(response.body)
        console.log(typeof(response.body))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})();
```

But i got the error: HTTPError: Response code 400 (Bad Request)

It work with other url and i see the data in my Web browser.
So i don't understand what is the problem...

Comment: They use cookies to ensure that each user gets their custom input. You can't just do a simple get request for receiving your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site requires a cookie in the headers to send you the data

Adding a cookie solves the issue

```
import got from 'got';


(async () =>{
    const url = 'https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1/input'
    try {
        const response = await got.get(url, {
          headers: {
            "cookie": /* your cookie here */
          }
        });
        console.log(response.body)
        console.log(typeof(response.body))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you it need a session, i will try with it

Comment: I'm still getting a 400 even with the cookie. Doing the same request from the command line works, but not from a website that is not adventofcode.com.

Comment: @MichielBorkent Is that a CORS issue? Why do you need to make the request from a browser? You might want to open a new question explaining your use case.

Comment: Already fixed by writing a proxy.